# Diagnostic Monitor Trace Listener

Tags: windows, azure, listener, trace, diagnostics

I would like to know if it is possible to modify the way the Trace is recording trace information ?

```
        Trace.Listeners.Add(new DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener());
        Trace.TraceInformation("OnStart");
```

I would like to be able to use the current WADLogsTable and adding one or more custom columns to the table. 
Right now the default table created by the DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration looks like that:

PartitionKey|RowKey|Timestamp|EventTickCount|DeploymentID|Role|RoleInstance|Level|EventID|Pid|TiD|Message|

I would like to add at the end some custom columns like :

PartitionKey|RowKey|Timestamp|EventTickCount|DeploymentID|Role|RoleInstance|Level|EventID|Pid|TiD|Message|Custom1|Custom2

So every time I trace something I am able to add data for those two custom columns
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to do this. While Windows Azure Diagnostics is quite extensible, you'll not be able to modify schema for trace logging. I would recommend looking into implementing custom diagnostics. You may find this link useful for this: http://convective.wordpress.com/2009/12/08/custom-diagnostics-in-windows-azure/.

Answer (score 0):

As Gaurav mentioned, this is not doable with default implementation of Trace.

I'd recommend using something like [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) and implementing a custom Table Storage appender.  I've done this on a number of projects and it works wonderfully.  It (Log4Net) can also consume regular Trace messages and log them into its storage